# cant download file with curl

Tags: curl

I'm trying to download a file with curl. To do these, first I must be logged in to be able to download the file. I'm trying with curl but it doesn't work. I saw the HTTP Headers and I don't understand why doesn't it work. Any help is appreciated.
The commands that I use are:

```
curl -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.4) Gecko/20091030 Gentoo Firefox/3.5.4' --referer http://www.sportstracklive.com/signin -d 'userCredentialsForm.userCredentials.email=USERNAME%40gmail.com&userCredentialsForm.userCredentials.password=PASSWROD&_target1=Login' https://www.sportstracklive.com/signin -c cook.txt -v > pepelu

curl -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.4) Gecko/20091030 Gentoo Firefox/3.5.4' --referer http://www.sportstracklive.com/signin -b cook.txt -v http://www.sportstracklive.com/user/username > pepelu2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine for me.

```
curl -L -c trackcookie.txt -d 'userCredentialsForm.userCredentials.email=flesk@gmail.com&userCredentialsForm.userCredentials.password=flesk&_target1=Login' https://www.sportstracklive.com/signin > track.html
```

If you want any other page after you log in, you have to use `-b trackcookie.txt`:

```
curl -L -b trackcookie.txt https://www.sportstracklive.com/user/pepelu > pepelu.html
```

You always need the `-L` option to log on to pages with cookie based authentication, because a cookie needs to be sent as part of the headers before any html, so it needs to redirect. The exception is cookies written by javascript, but that's another chapter.

**EDIT:** You're right. I wasn't logged in after all. The correct way to log in is:

```
curl -Lc trackcookie.txt http://www.sportstracklive.com/ > /dev/null
curl -Lb trackcookie.txt -d 'userCredentialsForm.userCredentials.email=flesk@gmail.com&userCredentialsForm.userCredentials.password=flesk&_target1=Login' https://www.sportstracklive.com/signin > /dev/null
curl -Lb trackcookie.txt http://www.sportstracklive.com/live/track/gpx?userid=31746 > mytracks.zip
```

The cookie actually lives on after you log out, so it seems like it's this sequence of server requests that determines whether the session id in the cookie corresponds to a valid session or not. I figured that out after I got to download the zip file with curl using the same session id set in Firefox when I was logged in there, but only then.

Comment: If you log in the page. In the right side, there is 3 options that there are if you are log in: (Facebook App, Download all tracks (GPX format) and View all tracks). When I execute the second sentence to download the source code I dont see these options. It seems that I'm not log in. Any help please?

Comment: @user650034: You're right. It wasn't working, but I figured it out. I haven't encountered this particular log in scheme before.

Comment: Thanks Flesk but doesn't works, the zip file isn't a file file, is only html file and you can see inside that you are not logged in. Any help please???

Comment: @user650034: Are you sure you've tried with the method I edited in? Note that the request to http://www.sportstracklive.com/ before logging in is crucial, so there are 3 invocations of curl needed. I tried it myself, and it works perfectly for me. I get a zip file containing all my gpx-files.

Comment: @user650034: You have to change the userid in the third url of course, but I assume you've done that?

Comment: @user650034: My pleasure. :) I enjoy a good challenge, and this one really had me scratching my head. If you're having trouble getting the next part to work, just submit a new question on SO. I always drop in on questions tagged curl.